# How can UDPROS be turned on for turtlesim topics/services?

Tags: ros, udpros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS Community,

How can we setUp turtlesim to support UDPROS topics/services? I'd like to test my ROS Client UDPROS implementation on ROS Subscriber Topics, and Services, and do not know what to configure to achieve this.

Thanks,

Aaron

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89366/how-can-udpros-be-turned-on-for-turtlesim-topics/services?/) by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4485/unknown_entity1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2013-10-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-11**:
Please edit your question to explain what you want to do more.  This question is way too generic to be answerable.

**Comment by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4485/unknown_entity1/) on 2013-10-11**:
@tfoote - Thanks. Edit performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To prefer UDPROS use [Transport Hints](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Transport_Hints)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4485/unknown_entity1/) on 2013-10-11**:
Unfortunately, preferring UDPROS does not make UDPROS work for me on Turtlesim. I've already made the preference, and UDPROS is not starting on ROS side. It stays TCPROS. Did you test this and verify it turns on UDPROS in turtlesim when you set the TransportHint via the ROS Client?

I am assuming TransportHints is the same as using the ROS Master/Slave API to call requestTopic(caller_id, topic, protocols), where protocols are the ordering of the preferred protocols?